# How to use subprocess and os modules to run commands in terminal (mac os)?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, subprocess

I have never used `subprocess` or `os` modules in Python. 
I want to run this exact command in my terminal:

```
python3 validation.py -i file_data.xlsx
```

I want to do this using `subprocess` in a `.py` file. 
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation and examples in the Python documentation for the modules you mention? If so, what code did you try - please edit a [mre] of your code into your question and explain what it does which isn’t what you want.

Comment: Depending on what you are intending, maybe you want something like:
```
subprocess.call("python3 validation.py -i file_data.xlsx")
```
or 
```
subprocess.Popen(["python3", "validation.py", "-i", "file_data.xlsx"])
```
That's assuming you want to call the command you provided from Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to use it in `example.py`

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['python3', 'validation.py', '-i', 'file_data.xlsx'])
```

For more usages, visit https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html